# Find middle element of Linked List

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

We have a Linked List of 'n' elements. How can I find the middle element?

Can I do it like this? (It's a pseudocode)

```
Node current = head;
for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
{
    current = current.next;
}
return current;
```

Comment: Why not try it and see if it works and if it doesn't then come back and ask a question about real code?

Comment: Usually when this question is asked, you can't assume that you have `n` as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your code is correct. Below is another way of doing it using Tortoise and Hare algorithm.

```
if(head == null) return head;
if(head.next == null || head.next.next == null) return head;


Node slow = head,fast = head.next.next;

while(fast != null && fast.next != null){
    slow = slow.next;
    fast = fast.next.next;
}


if(fast != null) slow = slow.next;

Console.writeLine(slow.data);
```

- If list is `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` => this returns `4`.
- If list is `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` => this returns `3`.// if you wish you can return `4` through slight modifications.
- If list `[1]` or `[1,2]` => it returns `1`// again you could modify this according to your need.

Comment: Thank You for comment. I know that solution, but I want to know is my question right or wrong? And if it's wrong, why?

Comment: @Joe, updated my answer

Comment: @Joe Welcome :)

Comment: @Joe while your code is correct, vivek's code has the benefit of not knowing the length of the linked list in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Simplement :

```
var current = list.ElementAt(list.Count()/2);
```

Comment: I think you cannot access elements in a LinkedList<T> via indices in c#

Comment: Since this is a linked list, this answer won't work. you can't access elements by index

Comment: @Oerk Thank for the comments

Comment: @ThierryV you're welcome

Comment: @ThierryV You still have the wrong brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified algorithm:

```
var enumerator1 = linked.GetEnumerator();
var enumerator2 = linked.GetEnumerator();
int count = 0;
while (enumerator1.MoveNext())
{
    count++;
    if (count % 2 == 0)
        enumerator2.MoveNext();
}
```

Second pointer is moved every two movements of main pointer.